# Struts2 Form Theme Simple: Error Message on the wrong position

Tags: java, html, struts2

I want my error message to the right side of my field. However when the password field has an error, the error message of the password is on the right side of the userName field. Why does it behave that way? base on the w3schools my format is correct. The error message password not correct should be on the right side of the password field.

This is the pattern I am following inside my form.

```
<table border="1">

      <tr>
        <td>UserNAme</td>
        <td>UserName Error message</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>Password Error Message</td>
      </tr>


    </table>
```

This is my Struts2 Code.

```
 <!--Struts2 log-in-->
                            <s:form method="POST" action="login" theme="simple"  >  
                                <table border="1"  >
                                    <tr>

                                        <td>
                                            UserName:<s:textfield label="UserName"  key="userName" maxLength="20"/>
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="errorMessage">
                                            <s:property  value="fieldErrors.get('userName').get(0)"  /> 
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>

                                        <td>
                                            PassWord:<s:password  label="Password"  key="password" maxLength="20"/>
                                        </td>

                                        <td class="errorMessage">
                                            <s:property value="fieldErrors.get('password').get(0)" /> 
                                        <td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr> 
                                        <td>
                                            <s:submit  value="Login" align="center"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </s:form>

This is the html result of the struts.

  <!--Struts2 log-in-->
                        <form id="login" name="login" action="/springtest/login.action" method="POST">  
                            <table border="1"  >
                                <tr>

                                    <td>
                                        UserName:<input type="text" name="userName" maxlength="20" value="tok" id="login_userName"/>
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="errorMessage">
                                        Username don't exist.
                                    </td>

                                </tr>

                                <tr>

                                    <td>
                                        PassWord:<input type="password" name="password" maxlength="20" id="login_password"/>
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="errorMessage">

                                    <td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="submit" id="login_0" value="Login"/>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Because Struts2 use Themes & Templates.

This may help you.

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/working-with-struts-2-theme-template/

Answer (score 0):

According To Your Problem CSS will play the lead role just take the field error through the action class .But you should specify the errors in action class.

There Are 2 types of errors are present

1)field error 
2)action error

This Field error Will Show the error on the upper side of the application.
then through css you can align the field errors.

For More Benefit you can use this link it will helpful

[Struts Login Application](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-validation-using-xml-example-1.html)

Comment: I am using the simple theme. The suggestion above is a normal struts themre.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem i did validations using xml the error messages were not at the proper place so tried this solution see if it helps u

```
<td align="left">
        <div><s:fielderror fieldName="birthDate" /></div>
        <sx:datetimepicker name="birthDate"  value="%{employee.birthDate}" />   
 </td>
```

Comment: You mean the solution is align left? I tried it but it did not work... still the same... It is weird because the error message was placed on the username's second td..

Comment: i tried the DIV however it maked my form into a very large table.. [Please check](http://jsfiddle.net/toksis/4TAg7/)